# Creating a dataframe with text from a website

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe, web-scraping

I've been asked to create a data frame in R using information copied from a website; the data is not contained in a file. The full data list is at:

https://www.npr.org/2012/12/07/166400760/hollywood-heights-the-ups-downs-and-in-betweens

Here is a portion of the data:

```
Leading Men (Average American male: 5 feet 9.5 inches)

Dolph Lundgren — 6 feet 5 inches
John Cleese — 6 feet 5 inches
Michael Clarke Duncan — 6 feet 5 inches
Vince Vaughn — 6 feet 5 inches
Clint Eastwood — 6 feet 4 inches
Jimmy Stewart — 6 feet 3 inches
Bill Murray — 6 feet 1.5 inches

Leading Ladies (Average American female: 5 feet 4 inches)

Uma Thurman — 6 feet 0 inches
Brooke Shields — 6 feet 0 inches
Jane Lynch — 6 feet 0 inches
```

I am supposed to use R to create the data frame, where one column is Name, the second is Height (in cm), and the third column is Gender.

I have copied and pasted all data into Notepad, manually made three different columns, and converted height to cm by hand. But this is manually creating the data frame.

Is there a way to make a data frame in R using the data as given?

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some webscraping. the `rvest` package is popular for R but frankly I generally do my webscraping in python using either `selenium` if there's rendered JavaScript or using `beautifulsoup` and `requests` if I'm only looking for HTML. There are a lot of online resources to get started webscraping in R ex. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/beginners-guide-on-web-scraping-in-r-using-rvest-with-hands-on-knowledge/

Comment: See this about assigning values: [How to assign a value to a variable in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22591892)

Comment: It did help. Much appreciated. I managed to figure out the exporting into a file by calling the code after the **library(tidyverse)** an array and using the command ¨**write.csv()**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy that whole list and then use `read.line` to bring in the text on your clipboard into R. Then using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) you can extract the gender form the header of each section, expand it to the rows below, and then `separate` the first column to name and height. See below;

```r
web.lines <- read.delim("clipboard", header = F) # reading data from clipboard

library(tidyverse)

web.lines %>% 
  mutate(gender = str_extract(V1, "Leading\\s+\\b(\\w+)\\b")) %>% # extracting gender from headers
  fill(gender , .direction = "down") %>% # filling the gender for all rows
  group_by(gender) %>% 
  slice(-1) %>% # removing the headers
  separate(V1, into = c("Name", "Height"), sep = " — ") # separating name and height


#> # A tibble: 59 x 3
#> # Groups:   gender [2]
#>    Name                  Height             gender        
#>    <chr>                 <chr>              <chr>         
#> 1  Uma Thurman           6 feet 0 inches    Leading Ladies
#> 2  Brooke Shields        6 feet 0 inches    Leading Ladies
#> 3  Jane Lynch            6 feet 0 inches    Leading Ladies
#> 4  Nicole Kidman         5 feet 11 inches   Leading Ladies
#> 5  Tilda Swinton         5 feet 10.5 inches Leading Ladies
#> ...
#> 28 Dolph Lundgren        6 feet 5 inches    Leading Men   
#> 29 John Cleese           6 feet 5 inches    Leading Men   
#> 30 Michael Clarke Duncan 6 feet 5 inches    Leading Men   
#> 31 Vince Vaughn          6 feet 5 inches    Leading Men   
#> 32 Clint Eastwood        6 feet 4 inches    Leading Men  
#> ...
```