# Using reset match token \K with stringr functions

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I've been answering this [Creating a dataframe with text from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64377165/6461462) and I have experienced an odd case which I cannot wrap my head around.

We have the lines below copied to our clipboard:

```
Leading Men (Average American male: 5 feet 9.5 inches)

Dolph Lundgren — 6 feet 5 inches
John Cleese — 6 feet 5 inches

Leading Ladies (Average American female: 5 feet 4 inches)

Uma Thurman — 6 feet 0 inches
Brooke Shields — 6 feet 0 inches
```

I have provided the solution below, which extracts gender from the header line and fills the following lines/rows with that. The issue here's that it extracts the word 'Leading' as well as *"gender"*. I was expecting to be able to use `\K` (reset match token) to get rid of that, but that does not work.

```r
web.lines <- read.delim("clipboard", header = F) # reading data from clipboard

library(tidyverse)

web.lines %>% 
  mutate(gender = str_extract(V1, "Leading\\s+\\b(\\w+)\\b")) %>%
  fill(gender , .direction = "down") %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>% 
  slice(-1) %>% # removing the headers
  separate(V1, into = c("Name", "Height"), sep = " — ") 

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   gender [2]
#>    Name                  Height             gender        
#>    <chr>                 <chr>              <chr>         
#> 1  Uma Thurman           6 feet 0 inches    Leading Ladies
#> 2  Brooke Shields        6 feet 0 inches    Leading Ladies
#> 3 Dolph Lundgren         6 feet 5 inches    Leading Men   
#> 4 John Cleese            6 feet 5 inches    Leading Men
```

What I have tried was `Leading\\s+\\K\\w+` which seems to be working in the demo https://regex101.com/r/pYaW7a/1 but not with `str_extract`.

Comment: `\K` isn't a meta-character in `stringi` regex engine, see [ICU User Guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp). Only in base R, [TRE](https://laurikari.net/tre/documentation/regex-syntax/) or, if `perl = TRUE`, [PCRE](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: you could also do `'(?<=Leading\\s)\\w+'`

Comment: @rawr thank you. Yes, I can use other patterns, but I was wondering about reset match token in stringr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `\K` in `stringr` regex functions that do not support it (see the [ICU regex syntax documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)), because you have [`str_match` / `str_match_all`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_match) functions.

The [`\K` *match reset operator*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) that is supported by PCRE, Perl, Onigmo, Python PyPi `regex` and Boost regex libraries and thus also available in base R regex functions via `perl=TRUE` argument, is used to omit some text matched before the current position. The same effect can be achieved with capturing groups. The problem with `str_extract` and `str_extract_all` is that they do not keep the captured substrings in the output. `str_match`/`str_match_all` *keep* the captured substrings in their output.

See the R demo:

```r
web.lines %>% 
  mutate(gender = str_match(V1, "Leading\\s+(\\w+)")[,2]) %>%
  fill(gender , .direction = "down") %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>% 
  slice(-1) %>% # removing the headers
  separate(V1, into = c("Name", "Height"), sep = " — ")
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   gender [2]
  Name           Height          gender
  <chr>          <chr>           <chr> 
1 Uma Thurman    6 feet 0 inches Ladies
2 Brooke Shields 6 feet 0 inches Ladies
3 Dolph Lundgren 6 feet 5 inches Men   
4 John Cleese    6 feet 5 inches Men
```

Here, `str_match(V1, "Leading\\s+(\\w+)")[,2]` is used to match and *capture* one or more word chars after `Leading` word and one or more whitespaces, and return just the captured value by accessing the item at the `[,2]` index.

Note word boundaries are redundant here, there is an implicit word boundary between a whitespace and a word char, and  a `\b` after `\w+` is also implicitly present.