# How to store in R

Tags: r

I am new to R, please help me with this question "Create a vector using the range operator (the colon), that contains the numbers from 9 to 1 . Store the result in a variable called store_vector." I couldn’t  find how to store a data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57205677/6851825

Comment: These are like hated word problems, but `store_vector <- 9:1`, and back to the word problem: create a vector using range(:), this is 9:1, associate it with, this is `<-`, name the variable, `store_vector`, then, back to front, or end to beginning, `store_vector <- 9:1`. if your number runs are irregular, you'll put  c(around the ranges `c(9:1, 2, 4:7)`.

Comment: Storing is a loose term, the problem is really asking you to 'assign' that vector to some variable name. It is not really being stored (though it does live in active memory). The assignment (as Chris explained) is done with with `<-` . This arrow pointing to your variable name from your vector tells r how to find and call up that vector when you need it. If you do not assign it a variable name in this case `store_vector` you will be unable to use the vector of numerics when you want to use them.

Comment: This and many other basic questions would be answered if you read through “Introduction to R” which should be available from the pull-down Help menu in most IDE and OSes.